# python search word in specific paragraph

Tags: python

I have a files like DDDDMMYY.zip in multiple folders like below

```
/test/abc/DDDDMMYY.zip
/test/def/DDDDMMYY.zip
```

These files will be configured in the application to process the data. Just wanted to check regularly whether all the sub directories files are configured to process.Application config looks like

```
<config name=abc>

   Process <DDDDMMYY.zip>

<config name>

<config name=def>

   Process <DDDDMMYY.zip>

<config name>
```

Tried using `regex` but it gives results only for the available configs. Above mentioned is a example like this we have hundred's of config i wan to verify them all using script.

Please don't mind if question is too long, asking this as I am new to python.

Comment: What's an "available config"?

Comment: Means only which is configured in the application

Comment: I didn't get this question, What is your goal ?

Comment: What are you applying regex to? (And how? i.e. do you have python script you can share?) Are you also checking the directories - and seeing if some are new and missing from the config?

Comment: If you're asking "how do I iterate through a directory and do validation on each filename?", try [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

Comment: the goal is, we use to get new files under new sub-direcotries (eg:xyz) for processing these new files, it need to be added in the application config. (manually). if there is a miss i need  throw an error for the sub directory which is not configured. Please confirm if this makes sense to understand.

Comment: So, it sounds like you do need to iterate through a directory, finding sub-directories with certain filenames in that don't exits in the config? (I suspect it would be easier to not have this typed into config, but have a script that finds files of a given name in a directory and calls process)

Comment: @doctorlove- Thanks for the suggestion let me check